# Editing page leaving file-upload input empty to keep the file?

Tags: php, html

It may sounds not clear, but I'll try.

I'm working on my edit page where I can edit several input types as well as file.
I'm saving my files in my database with its filename.

However, since input type = file doesn't allow to keep the data / value on it, unless I re-upload the file, it will just wipe out the filename on my database.

How would I be able to keep the filename as it is in my database without re-uploading the file?

Comment: can you add what you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very simple. You just don't need to update the database field that containing the file name if the input file is empty.

Here is a demo for you.

Lest's assume your form is like this.

```
<form>
    <input type="file" name="myfile">
</form>
```

So you need to check this in your backend.

```
if(isset($_FILES['myfile']) && !empty($_FILES['myfile']['name']))
{
    // update your databse column with new file detail
}
```

Hope this helps.